# Rolling windows in pandas based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataset which looks like:

| column |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

I need to create windows, iterating over a list containing the window size.
The output should be

- when window size = 1

| dataset1 |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |

| dataset2 |
| --- |
| 1 |

| dataset3 |
| --- |
| 2 |
| 2 |

- when window size = 2

| dataset1 |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |

| dataset2 |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 2 |

the pseudo code should be

```
df is a dataframe
windows = [1,2,3]
for window in windows:
   create multiple rolling subdataset
```

#### EDIT

Unfortunately, I'm creating windows with different size, so the code looks like that

```
windows = [1,2,3]
for window in windows:
  L = [g for k,g in dataf.groupby('day')]
  dfs = [pd.concat(L[i:i+window]) for i in range(0, len(L)-window+1)]
```

Unfortunately, dfs will only store the dataframe created when windows == 3.
I need to access all the dataframe because I need to add a column for each.

I tried to store the dfs into a dictionary whose keys where the window size, but it tells that "dictionary is unhashable"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
L = [g for k,g in df.groupby('Index')]

n = 2
dfs = [pd.concat(L[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(L)-n+1)]

print(dfs)
```

output:

```
[   Index
 0      0
 1      0
 2      1,
    Index
 2      1
 3      2
 4      2]
```

###### update: multiple windows

```
windows = [1,2,3]
dfs = []
for window in windows:
  L = [g for k,g in dataf.groupby('day')]
  dfs.extend([pd.concat(L[i:i+window]) for i in range(0, len(L)-window+1)])
print(dfs)
```

Comment: @gingerbread_54 see update (this is no longer a pandas issue, more classical python)